# By click jquery accordion tab, files get automatically downloaded in chrome browser.How to prevent this automatic download

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

when i click jquery accordion tab, files get automatically downloaded in chrome browser. In the console,
following message will appear
**"Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type application/octet-stream: *'My file url'*"**.

How to prevent this automatic download?

Comment: What do you have contained within the accordion?

Comment: I have 5 tabs inside the accordion.In 4th tab i have list of files[audio,video,jpg,txt].when i click the 4th tab, file get started to download automatically in chrome

Comment: What HTML is in that tab?

Comment: we are using HTML5 version

Comment: Can you post the CODE used?

Comment: here the html code is

Comment: Thanks for your reply.After installed Quick time player, this issue is fixed.....